# Deleting values from column if they are smaller than a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro which deletes values from column if they are smaller than a specific value indicated somewhere else in the worksheet.

My try

```
    Sub clearsmall()
Dim r As Range
num1 = Cells(7, 5).Value
For Each r In Selection
If r.Value < num1 Then
r.Clear
End If
Next
End Sub
```

the problem is that thois requires the range to be selected by the user. Hoever, I want to specify it in the macro - using something like

```
Set r = Range("C16:C92")
```

how would I need to change the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub clearsmall()
    Dim cell As Range, r As Range

    Set r= Range("C16:C92")
    num1 = Cells(7, 5).Value
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value < num1 Then cell.Clear
    Next
End Sub
```

You can also shorten it down to

```
Sub clearsmall()
    Dim cell As Range

    Num1 = Cells(7, 5).Value
    For Each cell In Range("C16:C92")
        If cell.Value < num1 Then cell.Clear
    Next
End Sub
```

Finally, you may want to use ClearContents instead of Clear, to clear cell value only, which is faster. This will not touch formats

Comment: @Timheinerz, did you get through it?